# Accessing a secure site through squid proxy fails with X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, client-certificates, squid

I recently setup squid proxy on my home ubuntu 20.04 pc. I upgraded squid with an SslBump Peek and Splice patch to comply with TLS standards 1.3-1.4. I reconfigured chrome and firefox to use squid as a proxy. My https connecting and browsing is fine except for one banking site. The chrome error response webpage says =>

```
The system returned:

(71) Protocol error (TLS code: X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY)
SSL Certficate error: certificate issuer (CA) not known: /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert EV RSA CA G2

This proxy and the remote host failed to negotiate a mutually acceptable security settings for handling your request. It is possible that the remote host does not support secure connections, or the proxy is not satisfied with the host security credentials.
```

The squid log output is =>

```
1638157464.964   5198 <my ip address> NONE/200 0 CONNECT www.mybank.com.au:443 - HIER_DIRECT/<mybank ip address> -
1638157465.128    157 <my ip address> TCP_MISS/200 1311 POST https://www.mybank.com.au/mfor-Gracleauen-sure-a-namd-Trade-thee-sleedeces? - HIER_DIRECT/<mybank ip address> application/json
1638157466.131   1050 <my ip address> NONE/200 0 CONNECT login.mybank.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/<mybank ip address> -
1638157466.140      0 <my ip address> NONE/503 4467 GET https://login.mybank.com/internetbanking - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1638157466.589    419 <my ip address> NONE/200 0 CONNECT login.mybank.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/<mybank ip address> -
1638157466.597      0 <my ip address> NONE/503 4467 GET http://devops1:3128/squid-internal-static/icons/SN.png - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1638157466.711    107 <my ip address> NONE/200 0 CONNECT login.mybank.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/<mybank ip address> -
1638157466.719      0 <my ip address> NONE/503 4467 GET https://login.mybank.com/favicon.ico - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

HTTP 503 error - Service Unavailable server error response code indicates that the server is not ready to handle the request.

The 503 error indicates the bank server may not be able to handle the ssl-bump protocol??
But an internet banking service should be an expert in TLS protocol best-practice?

In any case, I thought maybe if I install the related root-certificate so that it is considered trusted, then the connection might work.

So I looked up the DigiCert CA provider and downloaded a DigiCertEVRSACAG2.crt file, which is the required format for loading into the ubuntu certificates store.

That was my next action :

1. Copied DigiCertEVRSACAG2.crt into /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
2. Ran : sudo -H update-ca-certificates which reported one warning =>

```
rehash: warning: skipping DigiCertEVRSACAG2.pem,it does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

3. I also add DigiCertEVRSACAG2.crt to the Chrome browser certificate authorities list, checking the "trust this certificate for identifying websites" checkbox.

Retried connecting to my banking website, no change, connection rejected.
I don't want to whitelist this website in my squid proxy config as certificate acceptance is absolutely required.

Does anyone have similar squid experience and a fix?